# Нет плавного сворачивания поля поиска

Tags: дефект, предложение, дизайн

There is no smooth collapsing (with animation) of the search field.

[image: animated screenshot]

Comment: Может так и задумано? В оригинале переход точно такой же.

Comment: @Egor, поэтому и [meta-tag:предложение] ;)

Comment: просто смутил {metatag:дефект}

Comment: есть, просто оно быстрое - записал видео, проверил :)

Comment: @PashaPash, да, кривую Безье надо было пересчитать, а у них одна и та же используется в обе стороны.

Comment: У меня намного более гладко работает, чем на примере в вопросе. Пожалуйста, укажите какой обозреватель вы используете?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, Хром.